# get facebook share counts wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, get

i still have a problem on http://www.whaelse.com/en/grau-gruen-schwarz/ with the share counter.

Twitter and Google+ works fine for me.

With this code i've tried to load the facebook shares.

```
function get_likes($url) {

    $json_string = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?id='.$url);
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);

    return intval( $json[$url]['shares'] );
}
```

and then

```
function getSocialCount($url){
    $urlCurrentPage = get_permalink($post->ID); 
    $strPageTitle = get_the_title($post->ID);

echo '<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' . $urlCurrentPage  . '">facebook<span class="facebooksticky">'.get_likes($url).'</span></a></li>'; 
}
echo getSocialCount( get_permalink($post->ID));
```

but i still get 0 shares counter.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a caching problem, just try it again tomorrow. Or try this endpoint, used by sharedcount.com:

https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=%%URL%%&format=json